# How to know if a DOM element mounted to tree

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am pretty new to DOM, I wonder if I refer a DOM element which may be removed from DOM tree, how can I check if it is still mounted or not?

Like:

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Then later I probably select `<div>` element and remove it, but this operation does only unmount those from the tree, the div variable still points to that DOM element.

**I wonder if there is a function to test if the div is still on the page (mounted on the DOM tree) or not?**

Comment: @Teemu An element can have a parent and not be part of the main DOM.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can probably try this one

```
document.body.contains(yourDiv)
```

contains method will return true or false

Comment: What if it is in the head? Or any other position in the dom?

Comment: @ВолодимирЯременко Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: @PeeHaa In general that's a valid concern, but the OP said that he added the element to the DOM with `document.body.appendChild(div);`, so we know it's in the body, and just needs to detect if it's been removed or not.

Comment: @PeeHaa
var yourNode = document.getElementById("yourID");
yourNode.contains(yourDiv);
=)

Comment: you can search the head+body with `document.documentElement.contains(yourDiv)`

Comment: How does it cost? O(1)? O(n)? (PS. O(n) is the complexity of linear search, DFS, BFS)

Comment: I found parentNode will be set null when removed. Determining by it costs only O(1), I guess

Answer (score 3):

**You can use [Node.isConnected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected)**

```
div.isConnected
```

Note: This will not work with old browsers (Internet Explorer, Edge < 79, Safari < 10)

Answer (score 2):

if a node is part of the document, its `baseURI` property will be a string URL, otherwise, it will be `null`

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV"), 
u1=div.baseURI, u2, u3; //first url, un-attached
document.body.appendChild(div);
u2=div.baseURI; //second url, attached
div.remove();
u3=div.baseURI; //third url, detached
alert(JSON.stringify([u1,u2,u3], null, 2));
```

run on this page in devtools shows:

```
[
  null,
  "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640316/how-to-know-if-a-dom-element-mounted-to-tree",
  null
]
```

this means that to determine if a node is attached, you can simply ask for `elm.baseURI`:

```
if(div.baseURI){ 
   alert('attached')
 }else{
   alert('not attached');
}
```

Comment: This is also not true, trying it in firefox 54 currently I see links in all 3 slots.

Comment: @php_nub_qq:  a year and a half is a good life for a patch. i'll check into FF and report back with a new idea.

Answer (score 1):

According to the improved version of [Mr Lister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016716).

```
function isMounted(node) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) return true;
    if (node.parentNode == undefined) return false;
    return isMounted(node.parentNode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Володимир Яременко's answer is correct, but as an alternative method, you can check if the div has a parent node.

```js
if (theDiv.parentNode==null) {
  // Not in the DOM tree
}
else {
  // in the DOM tree!
}
```

This will be null before appending it to the body, and again after removing it from the body.

Comment: This is not true, an element can have a parent without being mounted.

Comment: @php_nub_qq Can you give an example?

Comment: A detached sub-tree retains internal relationships. If there is `body -> A -> B` and you do `body.removeChild(A)`, `B.parentNode != null` despite not being mounted.